# Stacked and Grouped bars

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I implemented a test environment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hrN7XACcm2oZqS1udO8UwagAjWJinrGHZriLXNg38_g/edit#gid=1268616837

...and I'm trying to achieve what seems a complex setup, while I think it should be easy to do.

Thus my question: how is it possible to go from a graph like the following:

[image: normal graph]

..to a stacked graph like the following one?

[image: stacked by category]

Basically I have 7 macro-categories (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) and some sub-category for some of them (A, B, C).

What I'm trying to achieve is to have stacked bars based on the macro-category, while keeping the sub-category different values in a stacked appearance.

Please note: not all macro-categories have sub-categories (for example, 4, 5 and 6 have no sub-categories), and "A" for 1 is different from "A" for 2 (meaning that I don't need to sum up "A" values, as they are unrelated)

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding an extra sheet (or modifying the previous ones) with a column containing all macro categories (1,2,3,4,5,6,7) and next to them a column containing the subcategories just like in [this example from the documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9142829?hl=en) (go to Stacked bar charts). Let me know if that was of any help or if you need further advice.

Comment: thanks, I think that's exactly the route I took, you can see it in the same link above, it is slightly different now.

Comment: Hi! I have seen that the sheet has changed quite drastically, did you figured out anything or reordered the information? I cannot access the original sheet.

Comment: Hi :) I think the document never changed the shared permissions, it's set to "Who has the link can modify": https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hrN7XACcm2oZqS1udO8UwagAjWJinrGHZriLXNg38_g/edit?usp=sharing
Anyway, I've only added fictional names to categories in order not to confuse with A, B and C, but the structure is exactly the same.
Plus, I used some pivot tables in order to plot the data in a certain way, and the create 2 stacked graphs out of those tables.

Comment: Yes! Now I can access thanks :) I can see in your ```Graph by category``` sheet that you managed to stack the columns in the right way. What did work for you? Could you post it in an answer so that everyone with the same doubt can easily see it?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf yes I agree with you, will answer soon ;)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve it with the following approach suggested by a User in the Google Docs Help: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/31586398?hl=en#